# NAudio Converting to PCM?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, naudio

Using the SetOutputToWaveFile method in the SpeechSynthesizer class, I included a SpeechAudioFormatInfo class with these parameters

```
new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 10000, 16, 1, 16000, 2, null);
```

My intent is to get the output to be 10kHz signed 16-bit little endian headerless raw mono PCM, and am now trying to understand how to harness NAudio to do that. I tried to base code on [change wav file ( to 16KHz and 8bit ) with using NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647730/change-wav-file-to-16khz-and-8bit-with-using-naudio) with WaveFormat and WaveConversionStream but am not getting the output I need. Can anyone refer me to working sample code?

Thanks.

Comment: 10khz is pretty unusual format, standard are 8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100, 48000, you need to try one of those values probably.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, I am using 10KHz because the destination audio is for a retro piece of hardware that uses 10KHz. I would use a standard one if I could. So....