# How to change BitsPerSample of wav file using Taglib#?

Tags: wav, taglib, taglib-sharp

I have sample wav file.I want to change BitsPerSample of it. I have tried with Taglib#. I have changed source code of taglib to make BitsPerSample editable. it's showing as changed in file.Properties.BitsPerSample Field while debugging but when I run program again its showing as previous value not the changed value.

Answer (score 1):

TagLib# can only read the audio properties of a file, it doesn't have the capability of altering those audio properties.  You would need a different library, such as [naudio](/questions/tagged/naudio), to do that.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647730/change-wav-file-to-16khz-and-8bit-with-using-naudio) uses NAudio to do something similar to your requirements.