# How to reduce file size/compress mp3 file with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I have 1000 mp3 files (like podcasts) approximately to be compressed, they have 64kb/sec bit rate in general. (a few in 192kb). Totally they take up 7,36 GB. What I want to achieve is to reduce it down to 1 GB with an acceptable quality.

I came up with [NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647730/change-wav-file-to-16khz-and-8bit-with-using-naudio) tutorials which edit the sample rates to lower size but eventually it didn't help me. (Some of files' size decreased but other some's increased)

I am too far away to audio world, is there a way to achieve this **programatically**?

Comment: This question is too general. But basically you'll have to transcode the files and encode at a lower bit rate sacrificing quality.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Wyck, this is what I need, ready to sacrifice quality, I tried the code in the link I shared to resample my files, but as I said I couldn't get a reliable result, for example, a file was 5MB after the execution of the code, the result was 10MB.

Comment: Show your `Encode` call.  What input and output bit rates were you trying?